# equalto in v 2.0.7 in my Rails 3 app is not working for a password confirmation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parsley.js

I have a simple user sign in form I am using parsely js.  Everything else is working fine except when I use the 'equalto' function here is my code:

```
<%= form_for @user, data: "data-parsley-validate" do |f|%>
<div class="field">
<%= f.collection_select(:title_id, Title.all, :id, :title_name, {autofocus: true, :prompt => "Title"}, {:class => "labels", :required => true})%>
```

```
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :first_name, "First Name *" %><br />
<%= f.text_field :first_name, :required=> true %>
</div>

<div class="field">
<%= f.label :second_name, "Family Name *" %><br />
<%= f.text_field :second_name, :required=> true %>
</div>

<div class="field">
<%= f.label :email, "Email address *" %><br />
<%= f.text_field :email, :type=>"email", :required=>true %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :password, "Password *" %><br />
<%= f.password_field :password, :required => true, :minlength => "8" %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Password Confirmation *" %><br />
<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation,:required=>true, :minlength=>"8", :equalto=>"#user_password"%>
</div>

<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit "Create an Account: move to next step", class: "btn btn-success labels"  %>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message, or is the validation just not working? Try using a JavaScript debugging tool such as Firebug to see what's going on.

Comment: Hi Alexander - I have used the javascript debugging tool and inspected the HTML and the parsely js documentation and code that I downloaded, even when I use data-parsely-equalto="#user_password" still doesn't work ?

Comment: Sorry more info : the required validation is working just not the equalto.

Comment: That's strange. Your code looks to be fine. Did you check that the rendered HTML of the password confirmation field is what you expected? Also, try restarting your Rails server. Sometimes validation libraries don't refresh when you would expect them.

Comment: Hi Alexander, parsely changes the class on the input to 'parsely-success' even when it does not match the password.

Comment: Just a update - I never actually got this to work and had to create my own validator.  A bit of a fudge so I haven't posted the code and just used the CSS classes from parsely.

Comment: Sorry that I couldn't be more helpful. Going forward, you might want to check out [jQuery Validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org) if you haven't already. I've used it and its `equalTo` functionality, and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

**form_id** = id written in form tag

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
  $("#form_id").validate({
    debug: true,
    rules: {
        "user[password]": {minlength: 6},
        "user[password_confirmation]": {equalTo: "#user_password"}
    }
  });
  jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
    equalTo: "Confirm password should be same as password."
  });
});
```